# How to avoid OutOfMemoryError in a small ArrayBuffer in a scope of small function?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The function `scanFolder()` was running, but sometimes exception bellow is produced

```scala
object MyClass{
    // ... etc
    val fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())
    // .. etc
    val dbs = scanFolder(warehouse)
    val dbs_prod = dbs.filter( s => db_regex.findFirstIn(s).isDefined )
    for (db <- dbs_prod)
      for (t <- scanFolder(db) {
            var parts = 0; var size = 0L
            fs.listStatus( new Path(t) ).foreach( p => {
                parts = parts + 1
                try { // can lost partition-file during loop, producing "file not found"
                    size  = size  + fs.getContentSummary(p.getPath).getLength
                } catch { case _: Throwable => }
            }) // p loop, partitions
            allVals.append(  s"('${cutPath(db)}','${cutPath(t)}',${parts},${size},'$dbHoje')"  )
            if (trStrange_count>0) contaEstranhos += 1
      }

    def scanFolder(thePath: String, toCut: Boolean = false) : ArrayBuffer[String] = {
        val lst = ArrayBuffer[String]()
        fs.listStatus( new Path(thePath) ).foreach(
            x => lst.append(  cutPath(x.getPath.toString,toCut)  )
        )
        lst.sorted
    }
}
```

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:448)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:109)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:93)
        ...
```

---

### (edit after more tests)

I am using Scala v2.11 (and save data after loops using  Spark v2.2).

I changend the code, elimitating all use of function `scanFolder()` calls, to avoid use of ArrayBuffer. Now is using directally the iterator `fs.listStatus( new Path(x) ).foreach( ...code... )` in the second loop.

... The program run during ~30 minutes... during some messages:

```
Exception in thread "LeaseRenewer:spdq@TLVBRPRDK" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "refresh progress" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "dag-scheduler-event-loop" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "dispatcher-event-loop-23" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "dispatcher-event-loop-39" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Final error message, stoping the program:

```
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "SparkListenerBus"
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
19/10/16 18:42:14 WARN DefaultPromise: An exception was thrown by org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler$$Lambda$16/773004452.operationComplete()
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
19/10/16 18:42:14 WARN DefaultChannelPipeline: An exception 'java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space' [enable DEBUG level for full stacktrace] was thrown by a user handler's exceptionCaught() method while handling the following exception:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Comment: This happens because you are creating so many objects in a short period of time that the GC barely has time to clean them all up. The culprit could be `new Path...` or `x.getPath.toString`

Comment: Hi @jrook, make sense (!), the most intensive loop (with a lot of `p.getPath`)  is the most internal, `p`... I edited the question, replacing the "...  do something..." to the real-life fragment. Perhaps now you can see the real cause of the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @SergeyRomanovsky good clues I solved the problem... Here a fragment that I used first with Spark-Shell (`sshell` on my terminal),

1. Add memory by most popular directives, `sshell --driver-memory 12G --executor-memory 24G`
2. Remove the most internal (and problematic) loop, reducing int to `parts = fs.listStatus( new Path(t) ).length` and enclosing it into a `try` directive.
3. Adding more one `try` directive to run the most internal loop after the success of the *try*  `.length`.
4. Reduced the `ArrayBuffer[]` variables to a minimal, removing the old `scanFolder()`.

Complete fragment:

```scala
// ... val allVals = ArrayBuffer[String]()
// for loop:
      var parts = -1
      var size = -1L
      try { // can lost partition-file during loop, producing "file not found"
          val pp = fs.listStatus( new Path(t) )
          parts = pp.length
          pp.foreach( p => {
              try { // timeOut and other filesystem bugs
                  size  = size  + fs.getContentSummary(p.getPath).getLength
              } catch { case _: Throwable => }
          }) // p loop, partitions
      } catch { case _: Throwable => }
      allVals.append(  s"('${dbCut}','${cutPath(t)}',$parts,$size,'$dbHoje')"  )
```

PS: for item 1 on compiler, use `SparkSession.builder()... .config("spark.executor.memory", "24G").config("spark.driver.memory", "12G")`

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the answer to your specific question. But I'd like to give some recommendations which could be helpful:

- prefer stream style of processing, i.e. avoid loops. Use `map`, `filter`, `fold`, etc. Don't use global state like `lst` and `allVars` in your code snippet.
- avoid unnecessary sorting. `scanFolder` ends with sorting without a clean reason.
- consider adding more heap memory for your task, this will reduce GC pressure.
- use a JVM profiler to narrow down a specific piece of code greedy for memory allocations. In your case you won't need that, as it pretty obvious. But in trickier cases it could help a lot.

Comment: Thanks, good clues!  About "more heap memory", [is this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/12191)?